# javascript, Display text when pusing button (multiple buttons) but only one text at the time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this javascript to display text when clicking a button in a website:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function toggleMe(a)
        {
        var e=document.getElementById(a);
        if(!e)return true;
        if(e.style.display=="none")
            {e.style.display="block"}
        else
            {e.style.display="none"}
        return true;
        }
    </script>
```

and i'm calling the script with `<A Onclick="return toggleMe('content')" >[Website Content]</A>`

The problem is that i have three "buttons" (help, gpgkey, content) and i would like that only one text be displayed at the time. I've never done java before and Im not even sure of totally understanding the first code.

This is one of my attempts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleMe(a)
    {
    var e=document.getElementById(a);
    if(!e)return true;

    if(e==document.getElementById("content")
        {
        var f=document.getElementById("help");
        var g=document.getElementById("gpgkey");
        }

    if(e==document.getElementById("help")
        {
        var f=document.getElementById("content");
        var g=document.getElementById("gpgkey");
        }

    if(e==document.getElementById("gpgkey")
        {
        var f=document.getElementById("content");
        var g=document.getElementById("help");
        }

    if(e.style.display=="none")
        {
        e.style.display="block"

        if(f.style.display!="none")
            {f.style.display="none"}

        if(g.style.display!="none")
            {g.style.display="none"}            
        }
    else
        {e.style.display="none"}

    return true;
    }
```

Comment: I have a question though.  You want to click one button and hide the other two?

Comment: @int21h, lets say that you click "content", the original script will display the "content text". Then if you click "help" it will display both texts. I just want to have one text at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function toggleMe(a) {
    var eContent = document.getElementById("content"),
        eHelp    = document.getElementById("help"),
        eGPGKey  = document.getElementById("gpgkey");
    if(!eContent || !eHelp || !eGPGKey)
        return;

    if (a === "content" && eContent.style.display === "none") {
        eContent.style.display = "block";
        eHelp.style.display    = "none";
        eGPGKey.style.display  = "none";
    }
    else if (a === "help" && eHelp.style.display === "none") {
        eContent.style.display = "none";
        eHelp.style.display    = "block";
        eGPGKey.style.display  = "none";
    }
    else if (a === "gpgkey" && eGPGKey.style.display === "none") {
        eContent.style.display = "none";
        eHelp.style.display    = "none";
        eGPGKey.style.display  = "block";
    }
    else if (a === "content") {
        eContent.style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (a === "help") {
        eHelp.style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (a === "gpgkey") {
        eGPGKey.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z68p7/